# Given two arrays of the same length, find which elements are "shifted"

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

To start, here are some examples.

```
['d', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['c', 'd', 'e', 1, 2]
// desired result: [1, 2]

[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
// desired result: [4]

['Hello', 'Goodbye', 'Goodbye', 'Hello']
['Goodbye', 'Hello', 'Goodbye', 'Goodbye']
// desired result: ['Goodbye', 'Goodbye']
```

The elements are shifted n indexes (where n is less than the length of both arrays). The arrays are always the same length. They are always shifted from the right side of the array. Is there a way to do this?

I was thinking of finding the largest subset in both arrays then taking the right or something. Can't find a great way to approach it

Comment: Shouldn't the last result be `['Goodbye', 'Goodbye', 'Goodbye', 'Goodbye']?

Comment: shift off the A until they match, then take a subset of B starting at A's new length.

Comment: To clarify, are the values of `n` in your examples `2, 1, 2`?

Comment: that is correct ryanyuyu

Comment: Any reason this is tagged [lodash] & [underscore.js]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic is somewhat simple, the major problem is to compare two Arrays.

I'm using the `JSON.stringify` to do that, but it's possible to loop through the Arrays too.

First you loop into arr `a` and shift it, until it has the same elements of the first items of `b`.

Then, you get the arr `b` and slice from the length of arr `a`.

```js
function findCrazyShifts(a, b) {
  while (JSON.stringify(a) !== JSON.stringify(b.slice(0, a.length))) {
    a.shift();
  }

  return b.slice(a.length);
}

console.log(findCrazyShifts(['d', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 1, 2]));
// result: [1, 2]

console.log(findCrazyShifts([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]));
// result: [4]

console.log(findCrazyShifts(['Hello', 'Goodbye', 'Goodbye', 'Hello'], ['Goodbye', 'Hello', 'Goodbye', 'Goodbye']));
// result: ['Goodbye', 'Goodbye']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function unshifter(a,b) {  
  while(!a.equals(b.slice(0,a.length))) {
    a.shift();
  }
  return b.slice(a.length, b.length);
}

// attach the .equals method to Array's prototype to call it on any array
Array.prototype.equals = function (array) {
    // if the other array is a falsy value, return
    if (!array)
        return false;

    // compare lengths - can save a lot of time 
    if (this.length != array.length)
        return false;

    for (var i = 0, l=this.length; i < l; i++) {
        // Check if we have nested arrays
        if (this[i] instanceof Array && array[i] instanceof Array) {
            // recurse into the nested arrays
            if (!this[i].equals(array[i]))
                return false;       
        }           
        else if (this[i] != array[i]) { 
            // Warning - two different object instances will never be equal: {x:20} != {x:20}
            return false;   
        }           
    }       
    return true;
}  

console.log(unshifter(['d', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 1, 2]));
console.log(unshifter([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]));
console.log(unshifter(['Hello', 'Goodbye', 'Goodbye', 'Hello'], ['Goodbye', 'Hello', 'Goodbye', 'Goodbye']));
```

This code uses [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Looks right to me. This JSFiddle shows it working for the three examples given, anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/4t5ajjnq/. You could improve this answer by including that `equals` method here and including those examples in a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Such a task can be achieved by iterating through the 2nd array (*b*) from the end and comparing backwards with a from it's end. Just a few lines of code, and this avoids unnecessary mutation of arrays. Can be further optimized at the cost of code complexity by skipping ahead ("accelerating" *i*) depending on what's found in the inner compare, but I left that bit out as it doesn't seem necessary here:

```js
function getShifted(a, b) {
  if(a.length != b.length)
    return;

  var len = a.length;
  for(var i = b.length - 1, j; i >= 0; i--) {
    for(j = 0; j <= i && a[len - j - 1] == b[i - j]; j++);
    if(j > i) {
      return b.slice(i + 1);
    }
  }

  return [];
}


function writeShifted(a, b) {
  document.write('a: ' + JSON.stringify(a));
  document.write('<br />');
  document.write('b: ' + JSON.stringify(b));
  document.write('<br />');
  document.write('shifted: ' + JSON.stringify(getShifted(a, b)));
  document.write('<br /><br />');
}

writeShifted(['d', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
             ['c', 'd', 'e', 1, 2]);
// desired result: [1, 2]

writeShifted([1, 2, 3],
             [2, 3, 4]);
// desired result: [4]

writeShifted(['Hello', 'Goodbye', 'Goodbye', 'Hello'],
             ['Goodbye', 'Hello', 'Goodbye', 'Goodbye']);
// desired result: ['Goodbye', 'Goodbye']
```